# Blocked iframe due to mismatch protocols

Tags: javascript, html, http, iframe

I am trying to send a value from parent window to my frame on button `click` event but it shows error on the console

> Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin
>   "http://localhost:53838" from accessing a frame with origin "null". 
>   The frame requesting access has a protocol of "http", the frame being
>   accessed has a protocol of "file". Protocols must match.

on the following line:

```
window.parent.setUpFrame();
```

I have the following code in the **parent container**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script>
function setUpFrame() { 
    var frame = window.frames['myFrame'];
    $('#btn-violet').click(function () {
        frame.changeTheme(2);
    });
}
</script>

</head>
<body>

<iframe id="myFrame" width="100%" height="300px" src="http://localhost:53838/" name="iframe_a"></iframe>    <input type="button" value="bisque Theme" id="btn-bisque" />
<input type="button" value="violet theme" id="btn-violet" />

</body>
</html>
```

And the code inside **frame** looks like this:

```
<script>
        function init()
        {
            window.parent.setUpFrame();
            return true;
        }

        function changeTheme(id)
        {
            if (id == 1) {
                $('#CustomStyle').attr('href', '/Content/StyleSheet1.css');
            }
            else
            {
                $('#CustomStyle').attr('href', '/Content/StyleSheet2.css');
            }
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your parent page is served through file this is the problem. You cannot mix a file page with an http nested frame. You should load the iframe from file as well.

Comment: What do you mean? The parent document is a simple .html file whereas the frame loads a .Net application running on localhost

Comment: This is the point both the parent page and the frame are to be loaded using the same protocol: file - file OR http - http. You cannot mix them: you cannot load the parent html with file protocol and the nested iframe with http

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you accessing your "main"-html via the file-protocol (just double-clicked the html?).

Please try to access via http://localhost:53838/ as well, or loading your iframe via file-protocol.

Comment: What do you mean? The parent document is a simple .html file whereas the frame loads a .Net application running on localhost

Comment: That is the point: Following the Cross-origin-policy, bot have to be served using the same protocol - if you have the possibility, just add the "simple .html" to your .NET app - and it will work.