# Can you use htaccess to change from https:// to coui://

Tags: .htaccess, protocols

I am writing code to interface with Microsoft Flight Sim and create an in-game display of my website.

MSFS uses javascript to do this and I can load my site in an iframe. I've come across a problem when I try to send messages to/from the page with postMessage and addEventListener. The error message basically states it blocked the frame with coui://html_ui with a frame with http://localhost. See picture...
[image]

I believe this might have to do with the answer in this question [Blocked iframe due to mismatch protocols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38072510/blocked-iframe-due-to-mismatch-protocols)

Is it possible to add something to htaccess to rename the http part to coui?? I know we have rewrite rules but not sure if this is possible or where I'd start? I believe that rewriteRule won't allow custom protocols? Can I use

This is my current .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -Multiviews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /flightcaseV2/public
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule  ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
  </IfModule>
```

I've found this answer here [How to handle mod-rewrite with a custom url scheme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24136175/how-to-handle-mod-rewrite-with-a-custom-url-scheme) which might help me? Will `RedirectMatch /(.*) myurl://$1` help me in my case?

Alternatively is there a way to send messages to/from the page without triggering this issue?

Comment: You can not just willy-nilly “rename” the _protocol_ part of any arbitrary URL to something else, and then expect things to still work. Assuming the client software in this instance already knew how to handle this `coui` protocol, then you would still have to teach your web server to “speak coui” as well. But without knowing any details about this protocol, no one could even say whether it would get all the necessary information this way. We don’t know what kind of request any client that understood what `coui://` meant, would even send in this case.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Just found this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24136175/how-to-handle-mod-rewrite-with-a-custom-url-scheme It looks like in that case they used RedirectMatch /(.*) myurl://$1 ????

Comment: But that would only take care of the redirecting aspect, nothing else. It doesn’t magically enable your web server to respond to a request for `coui://localhost`. If the request would even get that far - no way of telling, what request port the client would use in that case. But even if it did reach your web server, you’d still be left with the task of _implementing_ a new protocol it doesn’t natively speak there.